# What is the best way to make a Romaji to Japanese keyboard?

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, cjk, language-translation

I am sorry if the below info seems irrelevant or lengthy.

> TL;DR I am wondering what would be the best way to code an English
> input to Japanese output keyboard.

So I recently started learning Japanese, and with that I started using websites and apps like WaniKani and Anki to help me remember Kanji (Borrowed Chinese Characters). WaniKani has a simple and really good interface for answering questions, while Anki is a flash Card system that lets you make and manage cards of whatever you want to memorize.

So I thought of an idea that would get me best of both the systems, and now I am making a website that takes data from my Anki deck and uses that to quiz me on my website with a WaniKani like interface.

So for those who don't know, Each Japanese Characters can be converted to English counterpart based on their phonetics,

> For eg, **つ** --> ***tsu***

This is called Romaji Translation. Google Translate and WaniKani (and a lot of other websites) use this to convert Standard English Keyboard Input to Japanese.

So, back to my question, I was wondering what would be the best way to convert English input
like, ***tsu*** to ***つ***. At first I thought of going with regex and came up with this.

```
/((?:[aeiou])|(?:[kstpgzdnhpmr][aeiou])|(?:shi|chi|ji|tsu|fu|ya|yu|yo|wa|wo))/gm
```

The above regex just looks for patterns of Either **only vowel** or **consonant + vowel** or  **some special characters**.
This one isn't complete yet, since it can't detect double consonants

> ***kko*** --> **っこ**
> Which is different from ***ko*** --> **こ**

Another thing it can't do is find patterns like

> ***cho or chyo*** --> **ちょ**
> This is a combination character. Which complicates things a lot more.

If there's another better way of making it happen, please point it out or if I can somehow improve on the regex.

Also, there is one more thing,

Characters have, lets say, kind of an accent, called the ***Dakuten*** that changes the sound of the character, for example

> **は**　Which is usually pronounced as **Ha** can be turned into **ば** which sounds like **Ba**, Notice those two little lines, most characters can have those.

> Another form of it is the **Handakuten**, **は** **Ha** --> **ぱ** **Pa**.

> So the above combination and double consonants apply to these accented characters too.

So I came up with a solution to convert the normal character to the accented one, by assigning a key to shuffle through the different forms of that word.
An example,

```js
const keyboard = $(".keyboard");
keyboard.on("keydown", function(event) {
  if (event.key == " ") {
    // Disables the space key.
    event.preventDefault();
    
    var string = $(this).val();
    // Position of the text cursor.
    var caretPos = $(this)[0].selectionStart;
    
    // If there is no character before the caret.
    if (caretPos == 0) return false;
    
    // String Operation
    const invert = (char) => (/[a-z]/.test(char) ? char.toUpperCase() : char.toLowerCase());
    
    var newString = string.slice(0, caretPos - 1) + invert(string[caretPos - 1]) + string.slice(caretPos, string.length);
    $(this).val(newString);
    
    // Sets the cursor after the changed character (its older position after being reset by the val()).
    $(this)[0].setSelectionRange(caretPos, caretPos);
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

input {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <form class="col s12">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="input-field col s12">
            <input id="first_name" type="text" class="validate keyboard" autocomplete="off" autocapitalize="off" />
            <label for="first_name">Kanji</label>
          </div>
          Set the Caret after any charcter in the text box and press the Space Key.
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

All it does is find the character before the caret and change it to Uppercase or Lowercase.
Instead of changing cases, it will traverse an array of the different forms the character that is before the caret.

This project just uses **JQuery 3.6**
and Materialize for CSS.

Thanks for Reading through all that. And I appreciate any and all replies.
Please tell me if I missed something.

Comment: Can you use a translation api?  You mentioned that Google Translate can already do what you seek.

Comment: Translate APIs return the dictiomary translation of the word. What I need is sort of a direct input. If I enter **te** in the keyboard it should convert it into **て**.

Comment: An input converter of some kind.  [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/jd1ahctw/) is an example I put together using https://www.npmjs.com/package/jp-conversion

Answer (score 0):

Found exactly what I needed.

[wanakana.js](https://wanakana.com/)
It is sponsored by WaniKani creators.
wanakana also comes as a [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wanakana)

```
npm i wanakana
```